# HTML5 custom validation for passwords

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking to create an HTML5 custom validation message when I enter 2 passwords which don't match.

Here's my HTML and JQuery

HTML:

```
<form class="form-group main-settings-form" id="main-settings-form-password">

    <input class="form-control main-settings-form-input password-main" type="password" placeholder="Enter new password" id="new-password" pattern='(?=.*\d)(.{6,})' required>

    <input class="form-control main-settings-form-input" type="password" placeholder="Retype new password" id="confirm-password" pattern='(?=.*\d)(.{6,})' required>

    <div class="main-settings-form-buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger settings-edit-cancel">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">Save</button>
        <br>
        <br>
        <a href="#"> Forgot password? </a>

    </div>

</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () { //This confirms if the 2 passwords match

    $('#confirm-password').on('keyup', function (e) {

        var pwd1 = $("#new-password").get(0);
        var pwd2 = $("#confirm-password").get(0);
         pwd2.setCustomValidity("");

        if (pwd1 != pwd2) {
            document.getElementById("confirm-password").setCustomValidity("The passwords don't match"); //The document.getElementById("cnfrm-pw") selects the id, not the value
        }

        else {
            document.getElementById("confirm-password").setCustomValidity("");
            //empty string means no validation error
        }
        e.preventDefault();  //would still work if this wasn't present


});

});
```

The problem is, the message is always triggered even if the passwords *do* match. Please help me trigger the message only when the passwords dont match, and be allowed to safely submit when they do.

JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kesh92/a8y9nkqa/ 
password requirements in the fiddle: 6 characters with atleast one number

Comment: You should be using `.val()` instead of `.get(0)` to obtain the value of the password field(s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery `get()` returns the dom elements of each...they can never be equal

You want to compare values.

Try changing

```
if (pwd1 != pwd2) { //compare 2 dom nodes
```

To

```
if ( pwd1.value != pwd2.value) { //compare 2 dom node values
```

Note however that you also need to now consider empty values since you are over riding validty

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks a ton! I have a follow up question. If I changed my original code to  `var pwd1 = $("#new-password").value;` and `var pwd2 = $("#confirm-password").value;`and keep everything else the same, shouldn't it work? Because it doesn't, so just curious as to why. Thanks!

Comment: 2 reasons...you are trying to manage `validity` properties of those elements later on and also `$().value` is not a jQuery property....jQuery uses `val()`. Suggest you don't intermingle jquery and dom native methods so much. It will confuse you

Comment: or use a battle tested validation script and don't re-invent the wheel